# In Excel I need to find data on sheet3 from data on sheet1

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an Excel workbook with several sheets.  The column `'SheetA'!W:W` lists text that can be found within a column header on row `'Sheet3'!1:1`. For example, `SheetA'!W42` contains "B16". Cell `Sheet3'!CB1` has the header text "B16: Sample 40", so it would be the target column.

Example: Sample of `'SheetA'!W42`

[image]

In `'SheetA'!CD42` there is a formula that calculates the sample number that needs to be located in `'Sheet3'!A:A`. In the sample below, `CD42` displays the calculated value "30", which can be found in `'Sheet3'!A32`.

Example: Sample data from Sheet3 displaying the headers and intersection of the column header (B16) and row containing the sample number of interest:

[image]

The goal is to retrieve the contents of the cell on Sheet3 where the searched for column and row intersect and display it in a cell on SheetA. In the sample provided, on `'Sheet3'!CB:CB` intersects row 32 and on sheetA the value "0.1950581843" would be displayed.

Does anyone know how this can be accomplished?

Comment: I've read this a bunch of times and I'm still confused what you're try to do?   Yes you can have a simple cell reference between sheets for example: =Sheet1!A2 but that's so simple that I think what you are trying to ask is how to do table lookups on one sheet from a table located on another sheet?

Comment: @Tyson I think I'm going to try rewriting this with Excel's proper cell reference syntax, and encapsulating all cell contents in quotes. Maybe that will help. I'm twenty kinds of confused too, though.

Comment: Ok. Did what I could to fix it. Still confused as hell. Also, Excel is not a database!

Comment: Yes, it's a table lookup that I am trying to accomplish but I wasn't sure if this required vlookup, hlookup or if there was and easier solution.  I will try to untangle the question so it easier to understand my request.

Comment: @user3857791 No, I'd leave it as is. Now that I've seen it with the pictures embedded inline, and proper cell references spelled out, I think I've got it figured out.

Comment: @user3857791 What you need are functions that will return the cell references (I'll have to look them up) for the search result in `'Sheet3'!1:1` that begins with `CONCATENATE('SheetA'!W42,":")`, and the one in `'Sheet3'!A:A` that exactly matches `'SheetA'!CD42`. Then, use `INDIRECT` and `CONCATENATE` to build a reference to the cell that has the column of the first match and the row of the second. The one thing you ***must*** check though, is to be sure that all potentially matching values in `'Sheet3'!A:A` and `'Sheet3'!1:1` are *unique*.

Comment: Oh, wait... I'm making this too hard. `HLOOKUP` will work fine. One sec. Previous statement about uniqueness of lookup values still applies. This also assumes that all of your numbers in the "X" columns are perfectly sequential starting at row 3 and always sorted ascending.

Comment: @Iszi Thank you. I primarily use Excel for its basic spreadsheet functions. My boss though primarily makes databases with it and he thinks that because I fix PCs, I must be a computer guru. I'm not. Hardware is easy...Excel not so much. The more explicit you can make your solution the better because I'm really just trying to get a handle on these functions.

Comment: @Iszi Yes, the number in the columns titled "X" are sequential. The range is 1 to 40.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your above data, I'm going to make a few assumptions. If all of these are true, then an `HLOOKUP` can easily solve your issue. Otherwise, a more complex chain of functions may be needed.

Assumptions:

1. All relevant header texts in `'Sheet3'!1:1` are *absolutely unique* within that row.
2. All relevant header texts in `'Sheet3'!1:1` are of the format "[X]: [Y]", where:

   - [X] is a value that can be found in `'SheetA'!W:W`.
   - [Y] is the value in `'SheetA'!X:X` which is on the same row as [X].
3. All possible values in `'SheetA'!CD:CD` are searchable in `'Sheet3'!A:A`, such that they will be on the same row as the data intended to be retrieved.

   - I'm just putting this in because I noticed there seems to be some repetition of these values in Sheet3, and wanted to make sure there were no conditions under which you might be searching for a value in `'SheetA'!CD:CD` that was meant to be matched against another column instead (and therefore may produce inaccurate results if matched in `'Sheet3'!A:A`).
   - If said repetition is strictly for ease of reading, might I suggest using the "Freeze Panes" feature, instead?
4. All relevant values in `'Sheet3!A:A'` are perfectly sequential, starting with "1" in `'Sheet3'!A3`, never repeating within that column, and *always* sorted ascending.

Given the above assumptions, I built my own sheets with sample data which roughly represents your scenario.

Here's a partial screenshot of my "Sheet3".

[image]

And a partial shot of my "SheetA".

[image]

List of analogues:

- Sheet3

  - My A:A = Your A:A, BY:BY:, CA:CA:, ...
  - My B:B, C:C, D:D, ... = Your B:B, BZ:BZ, CB:CB, ...
- SheetA

  - My A:A = Your W:W
  - My B:B = Your X:X
  - My C:C = Your CD:CD
  - My D:D = Whatever column you want to drop the found data in.

As you can see in the second screenshot, the formula for D2 is:

```
=HLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(A2,": ",B2),Sheet3!A:Y,C2+2,FALSE)
```

Step-by-step walkthrough of the formula:

**HLOOKUP** lets you look horizontally through a cell range for a value, then return the value of a cell in the same column based on a relative row position. It takes four arguments, three of which are mandatory: *lookup_value*, *table_array*, *row_index_num*, *[range_lookup]*. This is the formula that will be doing the leg-work of finding the data you want in Sheet3, and pulling it into a cell in SheetA.

- ***lookup_value*** is the value you want `HLOOKUP` to find first. This value *must* be present in the first row of *table_array*, because that's the only row that will be searched. `HLOOKUP` also will only return the first match, so these values should also be unique. Here, we're using `CONCATENATE` to build our search string.

  - **CONCATENATE** lets you put together various strings and values into one string. It accepts a series of arguments, ordered according to the sequence in which they should be placed in the resulting string.

    - **A2** is our first argument for `CONCATENATE`. The first part of our string will be the "Sample Name" in A2.

      **": "** is our second argument to `CONCATENATE`. This puts the colon and space into the string, to match the format of values in `'Sheet3'!1:1`.

      **B2** is our last argument for `CONCATENATE`. It pulls the "Sample ID" from B2, to complete the syntax used for headers in `'Sheet3'!1:1`.

  ***table_array*** is a reference to a range of cells you want `HLOOKUP` to work with. Remember that the first row must be the one that will contain *lookup_value*. This range must also encompass all possible values for *row_index_num*.

  - **Sheet3!A:Y** is a reference to all cells in columns A through Y (the only ones populated in my Sheet3), of Sheet3. This ensures that any data added in new rows later on will also be in scope of the search. If data was going to be added in new columns instead of rows, I would want to use the reference `Sheet3!1:32` (currently, 32 is the last row populated in my Sheet3). If data might be added by new columns *and* new rows, I would reference the entire sheet with `Sheet3!1:1048576` or `Sheet3!A:XFD`. (Note: The "entire sheet" reference is valid for Excel 2013. Earlier versions may have smaller row/column limitations - adjust `1048576` or `XFD` as appropriate.)

  ***row_index_num*** is a positive integer representing a row position relative to the topmost row in *table_array*. This tells `HLOOKUP` which cell you want returned from the matching column. Note that, because `HLOOKUP` only searches for *lookup_value* in the top row of *table_array*, and *row_index_num* cannot be negative, you cannot use `HLOOKUP` (at least, not by itself) to return information from cells that are above *lookup_value*.

  - **C2+2** - Since all values in `'Sheet3'!A:A` are perfectly sequential, with no skipped integers, and will always be ordered ascending, we can use those values (also represented in `'SheetA'!C:C`) as indicators of the row numbers for the data we want to find. The `+2` is there to account for the fact that the numbering starts with "1" on row 3 of Sheet3.

  ***[range_lookup]*** is an optional argument for `HLOOKUP`. Options are TRUE or FALSE, to indicate whether you want to allow approximate matches to be valid or if only exact matches should be permitted. Excel defaults to TRUE (approximate matching) if this argument is omitted, which often can result in undesired behavior - especially if your sheet isn't sorted in certain ways. So, we specify **FALSE** here to make sure `HLOOKUP` will only pick up an exact match.

Adapting the above to your sheet's layout, I believe this is the formula you'll need for cell `'SheetA'!CE42` (assuming that's where you want the data to be dropped in):

```
=HLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(W42,": ",X42),Sheet3!A:CB,CD42+2,FALSE)
```

Note that, if your data in Sheet3 goes further to the right than column CB, and/or data may be added to further columns, you'll want to adjust *table_array* accordingly.